# Could not import Coder Style XML in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea

I couldn't import the templates.xml file to the IntelliJ IDEA Coder Style. It shows me some following error. Can anyone solve this problem? How can I modify the tempaltes.XML file for the successful import?

[image: Error message]

Comment: Where did you get this XML? How do you know it's compatible with your IntelliJ IDEA version?

Comment: Using Open MRS Repository, That is the latest version with the IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: `templates.xml` is for Live Templates, code style is in `OpenMRSFormatter.xml`. Pay attention to what you download and where you apply it.